# Using both JWT and Passportjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, passport.js

I am working on mern stack application where I use both jwt for registration and passportjs for social login. I am currently facing issue of authenticating routes.

Here is the Auth middleware of jwt and passportjs:

```
     const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
    const Auth = async (req,res,next)=>{
        //if(req,headers)
        try {
            const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
            if(!token){
                return res.status(404).json({msg:"no token authorization"})
            }
            let decodeData
            
            decodeData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
            req.userId = decodeData.user.id
            next()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send("Server Error");
        }
    } 
    
    const passportAuth = (req,res,next)=>{
        if(!req.user){
            return res.status(404).json({msg:"user not loggged in"})
        }else{
            next()
        }
    }

module.exports = Auth
module.exports = passportAuth
```

logged in user can create post but here I have jwt auth and passportauth.

if use both [Auth, passportAuth] in the route it wont be working becuase either user have to logged in with google or simple signup registration. Here is the authenticated route code

```
route.post("/",[auth,passportAuth], async(req,res)=>{
    const post = req.body
    try {
        const createpost = new Post({
            tags:post.tags,
            creator:post.creator,
            title: post.title,
            message: post.message,
            selectedFile: post.selectedFile,
            user:req.userId
        })
        await createpost.save()    
        res.json(createpost)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
})
```

So what should I do here?

Comment: route.post("/signup",[auth], async(req,res)=>{
    ...
})

route.post("/social-login",[passportAuth], async(req,res)=>{
    ...
})

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of returning error responses set some property on the response (something like `res.authenticated = true` / `res.authenticated = false`). Then have another middleware which would check if this property is set and only return error response if it's `false` or not present. You would just have to make sure that this middleware is called always as the last one (I don't remember now how it works in express).

As a side note - `404` response is `not found`. For the case of missing/bad authentication you should rather use `401`.